# Run Windows application as a service?

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

What is the cleanest, most reliable way to run a Windows application as a service without touching its code?

Use case: [NorthScale's 64-bit Windows version of memcached](http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-packages/) runs as a generic application. I'd like to stick it into a Windows 2003 or 2008 Service so I can start/stop/restart/etc it through the standard interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) has any executable, `srvany.exe` that can be used, as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890), to run basically any exe as a service. The setup is a little convoluted (requires a registry edit), but should work for most things that can be run as a user applicaiton.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the app there are a bunch of 'run as service' wrappers.
I have used cygrunsrv.exe, I think it works with non-cygwin executables.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the code then you cannot directly run the app as a service. However it should not be difficult to [Make a Win32 service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810429.aspx) - it all revolves around calling one api: [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686324(VS.85).aspx). In response to commands from the service control manager your wrapper service would CreateProcess etc. on the memcached application.